# Uncaught TypeError: answer.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, append, appendchild

This is all my code:

```
 <div class="conteiner">
    <h3 class="kitxva hide">Question</h3>
 <div class="questionCon " id="questionCon" >

    <button class="anwser1 ">Anwser1</button>
    <button class="anwser1 ">Anwser1</button>
    <button class="anwser1 ">Anwser1</button>
    <button class="anwser1 ">Anwser1</button>

   <div class="controls">
    <button id="start" class="anwser">Start</button>
    <button id="next" class="anwser1">Next</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
const start = document.getElementById('start');
const next = document.getElementById('next');
const questionCon = document.getElementById('questionCon');
const kixtva = document.querySelector('h3')
const anwser = document.querySelectorAll('.anwser1');


let shuffleQuestions, currentQuestionIndex


start.addEventListener('click',startGame);

function startGame(){
  for (var i=0;i<anwser.length;i+=1){
    anwser[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
  kixtva.classList.remove('hide');
  start.classList.add('hide')

  shuffleQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
  currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion(){
   resetState()
   showQuestion(shuffleQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}

function resetState(){
   next.classList.add('hide')
   while(anwser.firstChild){
     anwser.removeChild(anwser.firstChild)
   }
}
```

There is an error referencing `answer.appendChild(button);`.

Comment: 1) Typo. You're writing "anwser" not "answer". 2) In your code `anwser` is a _list_ of nodes. You need to identify the _one_ element you want to append the child to. 3) Your code doesn't actually include the line `answer.appendChild(button)` so there maybe more going on than just these issues. It's hard to tell.

Comment: Hi. I've fixed up the code formatting. The easiest way to format your code is to surround it with ```. I've also made the indenting clearer. Please can you edit the question to include the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `answer.appendChild(button);` in your code but I see that `answer` is `document.querySelectorAll('.anwser1')`.

Problem is that `querySelectorAll()` **returns all elements** as `NodeList` object - not only one element. You are looking for `querySelector()` which returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector or if you want to get all of your answers with `querySelectorAll()` you have to iterate over each element in `NodeList` (you can use `for` or `forEach` or anything like that).